# Is there any feature or function/library to connect sharepoint via HPQC?

Tags: sharepoint-api

I want to use my HPQC runtime data sharing on Sharepoint portal based on trigger from sharepoint. Is there any feature or function/library to connect sharepoint via HPQC?

Thanks,
Dnyanesh